# MVVM treeview selected item using converter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I am a beginner of MVVM. I wanted to bind selected treeview item to a textblock. I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17073163/1820828). So I implemented the same in my project...:

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource GetTextFromItemConverter}, ElementName=tvMain, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Also created the GetTextFromItemConverter class in my viewmodel(same as in the solution).
But in xaml I got error saying

> The resource GetTextFromItemConverter could not be resolved.

How to resolve this issue??

Comment: where do you declare the instance of your converter (with the resource key of `GetTextFromItemConverter`) ? I doubt you have not even declared any, and just use its class name for the resource key.

Comment: @KingKing Can you please tell me how to add resouce key of 'GetTextFromItemConverter'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the class `GetTextFromItemConverter` is defined in some namespace called `TestDemo`. You first have to create some instance of that class as some resource in XAML. As an example, you can add it as some resource of `Window.Resources`, we need to import the namespace of that class so that we can create an instance of that class, something like this:

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestDemo">
   <Window.Resources>
     <local:GetTextFromItemConverter x:Key="textConverter"/>
   </Window.Resources>
   <!-- ... -->
     <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem, 
                     Converter={StaticResource textConverter},
                     ElementName=tvMain, Mode=OneWay}"/>
   <!-- ... -->
</Window>
```

Note about the added part `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestDemo"` is to import the `TestDemo` namespace and aliased as `local` prefix. The `...` is a placeholder for what you have in your Window (auto-generated by designer).

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the view model that you have mapped is properly referenced, if so its perfect check for the path reference to the converter that you have used.

For example:

`xmlns:converter="using your namespace path"-location` where the converter is placed in the resource dictionary.